# Why do my video and audio lenghts not match when I cut?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I love this program! But for some reason I keep having this problem! The video clip is **not** sped up, or altered in any way. It's just cut off.

[image]

---

[image]
My FPS does match my file, I checked and double checked! That was my problem before... Some of my videos work, while others are cut off. I use the same recording software and settings for both. This is crazy and I'm very upset. The video is not slow or glitchy at all! Just CUT OFF.

Comment: Your project framerate doesn't match the one of your Video file.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43298/video-editing-audio-and-video-strip-have-different-length/43303#43303

Comment: @cegaton: As it seems to be a timelapse video here I won't count it as a real duplicate, but it's related of course.

Answer (score 3):

Set your project Frame Rate properly to match the one of your footage.

Mikeycal Meyers has got some great [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4) on this [topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Rdraa7YzcE&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIZOWRDICIZ2WCFapHHYLPv&index=16). He explains it pretty well in #[2 - Blender Video Editing (Importing video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_4198905327&feature=iv&index=3&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&src_vid=20VqQLpvctY&v=AveiZhv2xHs) starting at [3:35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_4198905327&feature=iv&index=3&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&src_vid=20VqQLpvctY&v=AveiZhv2xHs&t=3m35s). If you want to do speed change stuff instead you should follow his #[24 - Blender Video Editing (Speed up & Slow Down Audio/Video | Snap Strips option)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrX1sK_ZQqs&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=27)

So to fix it for you, you need to calculate your footages frame rate and set it up in Blender. You can do so by dividing your Audio Length (which is **42389** as you can see on your *teal/lightseagreen/darkcyan* colored Strip after the "|") by your Video Strips Length (that **3284** next to your *darkblue* strip) that is about *12.907...* When you then multiply this result by your current Frame rate (which is 30 right now in your Properties) to get the Footages Frame Rate. Which is about *2.32418...* in your case. It seems to be a timelapse Video Capture with a pretty low frame rate.

Here the result isn't a already predefined common Frame Rate. So you need to select a "Custom" Frame Rate in your Properties and leave this FPS setting at 30 and use this *12.907...* as your Framerate base below (you can directly enter "**42389/3284**" into the box and let Blender do the math. Your result should be the "**Custom (2.34 fps)**" in the Frame Rate Dropdown box.