# Video editor audio clip length

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am importing a 16 bit PCM microsoft wave file into blender video sequence editor.

When I do so, the audio playback does not match the visual length of the audio clip in the sequence editor. When I play the audio clip will be completed, but the green position marker is only half way through the clip. I know there is no dead space at the end of the clip either.

So this essentially makes it impossible to edit audio into my video because I have no clue where audio clips end....

Changing the position of the marker results in all sorts of anomalous behavior. If I move the marker to 50% of the clip, it will play the audio position of maybe 40% of clip length. If I move the mark to 75% it might play position 45% of audio.

If I start from the beginning of the clip, the audio completes before it even gets to the 50% mark of the visual clip.

It seems like the visual representation of the audio clip and the actual audio clip are totally out of whack...

EDIT: This is not related to the common problem of importing a video clip with associated audio at different framerate. My video files and audio files are separate and imported separately. The video is confirmed to by 30fps and project is set accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video editing. Audio and Video strip have different length](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43298/video-editing-audio-and-video-strip-have-different-length)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44060/2843