# audio track not add completely in blender

Tags: edit-mode, video, audio

i've workin on a fairly simple video editing, just add video clip and 1 song (7 min in length) but the problem is: i cannot add full length of audio, the last minute is not show in Video Editor. but i manage to stretch last bit of it, it seem the blender somewhat cut it to ~6 min, the problem is why there is no green filling in the last minute (red circle) and how can i import the song without length cut in blender?

[image: Problem on Audio Importing]

Comment: Are you trying to extend the audio past it's original duration?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44060/2843

Comment: no, i'm trying to export stuff without changing the duration. as you can see...the file length when imported is only the green filling, but i extend it, so i can go to full duration of the song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Properties panel > Dimensions tab*, change your frame rate to *30 fps*. The frame rate ofter affects the audio.

*24 fps, what you have:*

[image]

*30 fps, recommended:*

[image]

Comment: i'm not trying to sync the original video sound, rather i want to change the sound to song... as you can see from my image, the default duration of song that blender imported is only the green filling. but the actual song is longer than that, it seem that the blender somewhat cut it to just 6 min?

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing happening before. Are you sure that it isn't out of sync like I suggested? Are you sure the file isn't corrupted/in an abnormal format?

Comment: i use mp3 format i guess not corrupted tho, i can still expand it to it's end length manually and get the music to finish. even when i'm trying to import music only. but i can't do this everytime i'm trying to import music.
no, there is no video when i import it. i'm trying to import it music first then audio or the other way around and get same result.